# Form inside form ...even with AJAX?

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I have a big form enclosing a table,
and just a real small form inside one of the cells.

The do send differnt data, and even use differnt methods, one is Post, another Get.
Is there any way to make it work?...

The code looks something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
   ...
   <form method="GET">
      <input type="text"><input type="submit">
   </form>
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: I cannot post the code..... well just imagine one form inside another form, one uses get and another post....

Comment: Unless you *need* AJAX I think a nested form should submit on its own, but more details would help.  If you do need AJAX submission it shouldn't be hard (more details?).

Comment: The problem is that the nested form doesn't work... As expected, but I know there should be a work around.

Comment: Yes, I use Jquery but only for the huge form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate forms,
negative margin-top - this will do for now.

If I get sick with it, I'll add a navigational 'href' script directly to button linking it to input and onkeyup enter event.

Answer (score 3):

As forms do not work well within eachother, I tend to use 2 submit buttons with seperate id's and combine the forms. The processing php file then decides what to do with the data depending on the value submitted by the submit button ID. Your problem is the fact you have a GET and POST. What are the forms submitting/retrieving?

Comment: Yes, the form inside is the retrieving form, and should select a specific product. It must be also seen in the URL, like 'item?IID=1'.
The other form is submitting, and it uses post, there are just too many different inputs, and they're scatter all over the table.

Comment: Also to post your full code put 4 spaces before the opening tag of the code, and 4 spaces before the closing tag. We can then see what you are trying to do fully...

Comment: Yep, I did 4 spaces... but maybe there should be another line break. Anyway, someone has had fixed it.

Comment: I am not sure, but something I would try is submitting the internal form via Ajax with an onclick tag. That way the Ajax will specify how to handle that particular submit button. Would be nice to know exactly what you are trying to achieve with your forms... Or even view the full source to see if there is an alternative to your method. Am I right in thinking you are trying to retrieve data from the get form, to fill in a field in the post form?

Comment: Yes, correct, but I think it's just somewhat ridiculous to use Ajax to submit just a simple form with one input, we would have to create on key down = 13 (for enter) and on click events.... In that way we don't even need form, just JS and a href with URl.... I'm thing of something mroe simple. Maybe I should post the smaller form after the table, and then to position it as it were in the cell. Is there any way to stick it up into the cell without guessing the exact css offsets?

Comment: Yes I was thinking it was a bit over the top, but i'm not sure of any other method. Can you post a link to what your working on rather than the code? Without CSS I can't think of any other way other to do what you are saying. I think either way it sounds like your going to end up with messy code without doing it that way. Is there any reason you don't want to specify them?

Comment: Other than seeing your code, the only thing I can suggest is try the following link, and follow that, but it is far more complicated than specifying a position with CSS: http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2008/10/01/how-to-create-nested-forms/ Hope this helps...

Comment: This is how it should look:
[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/25803695.png/)
I just used a negative margin top for the small form, it works for now, but the second column might get bigger eventually, and it will pull the small form down...

Comment: I cannot access yout link it at the moment. It says I am banned. But I'll check it up later.

Comment: Maybe just wrap a div around the main form, specify a height (the height of the left column) allowing any overflow to be visible, and then set the negative top margin on the second form. You may need to set the positions of each form to relative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery submit method with the click listener.

For instance if your forms are structured like this:

```
<form id="outer">
    <form id="inner">
        <button id="innerbutton" />
    </form>
    <button id="outersubmit" />
</form>
```

Then I think this *should* work:

```
$('#innerbutton').click(function() {
    $('#inner').submit();
    //or an AJAX call
});
$('#outerbutton').click(function() {
    $('#outer').submit();
});
```

jQuery submit documentation: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Then I'd use separate forms like the answer you approved.